# Customizing marker in Map Component in iReport 5.6.0

Tags: google-maps, jasper-reports, ireport

How to set marker property in map component in *iReport 5.6.0*?

Comment: I have tried to set property in map component but there is no marker property available here ,I have also read documentation http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/map/index.html but it was of no help

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue I made changes in the xml of report and set marker item property for icon there,the following changes I did was:

```
<mp:itemProperty name="icon">
    <valueExpression><![CDATA["http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png"]]></valueExpression>
</mp:itemProperty>
```

Comment: <mp:itemProperty name="icon">
<valueExpression><![CDATA["http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png"]]></valueExpression>
</mp:itemProperty>